# C# MediaElement -- Why does Play() sometimes silently fail after switching the source?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I have a `MediaElement` set up in a custom UserControl for a video player control that I've been making -- play/pause button, slider, time remaining, etc. I have `ScrubbingEnabled` set to `True` so that I can show the first frame of the video to the user per the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346886/show-first-frame-of-video-in-wpf-mediaelement), and also use a `Slider` element to allow the user to scrub the video.

**Problem**: I use a binding to switch the video player's source. On occasion, if I switch videos *while a video is playing*, the `MediaElement` stops responding to `Play()` commands. No errors are given, even in the `MediaFailed` event. Calling `Play()` (or `Pause()` then `Play()`) fails every time. I can switch the video source after the `MediaElement` fails, and then it will start working again.

XAML:

```
<MediaElement LoadedBehavior="Manual" ScrubbingEnabled="True" 
              UnloadedBehavior="Stop"
              MediaOpened="VideoPlayer_MediaOpened" x:Name="VideoPlayer"/>
```

Pertinent control code:

```
public static DependencyProperty VideoSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("VideoSource", typeof(string), typeof(MediaElementVideoPlayer),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSourceChanged)));

private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElementVideoPlayer player = d as MediaElementVideoPlayer;
    if (player != null)
    {
        player.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            if (player.VideoSource != null && player.VideoSource != "")
            {
                if (player._isPlaying)
                {
                    player.VideoPlayer.Stop();
                    var uriSource = new Uri(@"/ImageResources/vid-play.png", UriKind.Relative);
                    player.PlayPauseImage.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
                    player._isPlaying = false;
                } 
                player.VideoPlayer.Source = new Uri(player.VideoSource);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void VideoPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        VideoPlayer.Pause();
        VideoPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromTicks(0);
        Player.IsMuted = false;
        TimeSlider.Minimum = 0;
        // Set the time slider values & time label
        if (VideoPlayer.NaturalDuration != null && VideoPlayer.NaturalDuration != Duration.Automatic)
        {
            TimeSlider.Maximum = VideoPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            TimeSlider.Value = 0;
            double totalSeconds = VideoPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            _durationString = Utilities.numberSecondsToString((int)totalSeconds, true, true);
            TimeLabel.Content = "- / " + _durationString;
        }
    });
}
```

If I tell videos to auto-play all the time, the player works 100% of the time, strangely enough. Unfortunately, I need videos to be paused when the source is set. **Does anyone know how to avoid the `MediaElement`'s random, hidden failure while still swapping videos, showing the first frame of the loaded video, etc.?**

There are eerily similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249084/why-does-mediaelement-sometimes-silently-fail-and-how-can-i-correct-it) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064775/mediaelement-fails-after-several-plays), but my problem has different symptoms since I am only using 1 `MediaElement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely enough, if you set `ScrubbingEnabled` to `False`, the `MediaElement` no longer stops responding at random times. Disabling `ScrubbingEnabled` breaks showing the first frame and makes the `Slider` element not function as nicely, so here's how to keep the those features while not having a, er, broken `MediaElement`.

**Showing the first frame:**

```
private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaElementVideoPlayer player = d as MediaElementVideoPlayer;
    if (player != null)
    {
        player.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            if (player.VideoSource != null && player.VideoSource != "")
            {
                if (player._isPlaying)
                {
                    player.VideoPlayer.Stop();
                    var uriSource = new Uri(@"/ImageResources/vid-play.png", UriKind.Relative);
                    player.PlayPauseImage.Source = new BitmapImage(uriSource);
                    player._isPlaying = false;
                } 
                player.VideoPlayer.Source = new Uri(player.VideoSource);
                // Start the video playing so that it will show the first frame. 
                // We're going to pause it immediately so that it doesn't keep playing.
                player.VideoPlayer.IsMuted = true; // so sound won't be heard
                player.VideoPlayer.Play();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void VideoPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        // the video thumbnail is now showing!
        VideoPlayer.Pause();
        // reset video to initial position
        VideoPlayer.Position = TimeSpan.FromTicks(0);
        Player.IsMuted = false; // unmute video
        TimeSlider.Minimum = 0;
        // Set the time slider values & time label
        if (VideoPlayer.NaturalDuration != null && VideoPlayer.NaturalDuration != Duration.Automatic)
        {
            TimeSlider.Maximum = VideoPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            TimeSlider.Value = 0;
            double totalSeconds = VideoPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
            _durationString = Utilities.numberSecondsToString((int)totalSeconds, true, true);
            TimeLabel.Content = "- / " + _durationString;
        }
    });
}
```

**Enable scrubbing for the video while the slider is being dragged:**

```
// ValueChanged for Slider
private void TimeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        TimeSpan videoPosition = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeSlider.Value);
        VideoPlayer.Position = videoPosition;
        TimeLabel.Content = Utilities.numberSecondsToString((int)VideoPlayer.Position.TotalSeconds, true, true) + " / " + _durationString;
    });
}

// DragStarted event
private void slider_DragStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragStartedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        VideoPlayer.ScrubbingEnabled = true;
        VideoPlayer.Pause();
    });
}

// DragCompleted event
private void slider_DragCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
        VideoPlayer.ScrubbingEnabled = false;
        TimeSpan videoPosition = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeSlider.Value);
        VideoPlayer.Position = videoPosition;
        if (_isPlaying) // if was playing when drag started, resume playing
            VideoPlayer.Play();
        else
            VideoPlayer.Pause();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been experiencing MediaFailed (MILAVERR_UnexpectedWmpFailure  HRESULT:0x8898050C) since introducing the ScrubbingEnabled property. Reliability has improved since disabling it during Play() and only enabling it during Stop(). That is; ScrubbingEnabled must be disabled when switching files.